# How do I remove the large right margin on the scrollbar in iOS Chrome?

Tags: css, ios, google-chrome, mobile, scrollbar

On:

- the current versions of mobile Chrome and iOS (13.3)
- the latest iPhone ("XS Max")
- many websites (e.g. https://www.allsaints.com/, but also occurs on a totally blank website with no content or styles)

there is a large amount of space
   between the y-scrollbar and the right side of the screen (indicated
   with red arrows in this example:

[image: example of ios chrome issue]

This space does **not** appear in Safari on the same device, nor on any browser on an Android phone or desktop.

I'm looking for a CSS property to use to reduce the size of, or preferably remove, this space. I thought the `scroll-margin` property sounded appropriate, but unfortunately that appears to deal with "scroll snapping" instead. Admittedly, with all the changes to scrollbars in 2019 I'm a little out of my element here.

Could anyone recommend one or more CSS rules to remove this space?